# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for not saving association on has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I am creating a project_management application 
when manager creating a project at that time I also want to save developers,
so for that, I created the user_projects model

but I not able to create the user_projects record

Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  scope :developers, ->{ where(:role => "developer") }

  has_many :developers, class_name: "User",
                        foreign_key: "manager_id"
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :user_projects
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User", optional: true

  enum role: {developer: 0, manager: 1}

  def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
  end
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, through: :user_projects

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_projects, reject_if: ->(object){ object[:user_id].blank? }
end

class UserProject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Projects Controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.user_projects.build
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:project_name, :project_description, :user_projects_attributes => [:user_id => []])
    end
end
```

Project Create form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@project, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :project_name %>
  <%= form.input :project_description %>
  <%= form.simple_fields_for :user_projects do |user_project| %>
    <%= user_project.association :user, :collection => User.developers, :label_method => :full_name, :value_method => :id, input_html: { multiple: true }%>
  <% end %>  
  <%= form.button :submit%>
<% end %>
```

getting errors

> errors prohibited this project from being saved: 
>  
>    1. User projects user must exist 
>    2. User projects project must exist

Comment: can you post the `user_project` model?

Comment: Sidenote: Your `developers` scope does not exist because the has_many is overwriting it. Think of it like this when you call `User.developers` which one do you expect? Instead remove the scope and change your has_many to `has_many :developers, ->{ where(:role => "developer") }, class_name: User, foreign_key: :manager_id` here the "scope" is included in the definition of the relationship

Comment: @thaleshcv user_project mode posted

Answer (score 0):

You should be accepting attributes for `users`, not for `users_projects` in your Project model.  This is able to work because you have set up the `has_many_through` association between User and Project.

Here's a simplified example that hits the critical points.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :user_projects
end

class Projects < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, through: :user_projects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem in your permit params, try to change it such as

```
user_projects_attributes: [:id]
```